# Is this algorithm for generating primes any good?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

We know that composite integers can be expressed as a difference of squares. $$N=a^2-b^2=(a-b)\times(a+b)$$

So if we wanted to generate primes using a difference of squares, we could simply multiply one of the square above by a non-square $(2,3,\ldots)$. We get $$N=a^2-m\times b^2$$

There are two simple precautions to take.

1. *Make sure that the two terms have opposite parity;* and
2. *Make sure that the two terms do not share a common factor greater than $1$.*

We provide a simple example to illustrate how the algorithm works.
$$N_{1}=13^2 - 2\times 1^2=167$$
$$N_{2}=13^2 - 2\times 3^2=151$$ etc... We don't always get a prime, like in $$N_{3}=13^2 - 2\times 5^2=119=7\times 17$$ but we often do. We can continue subtracting $$2\times b^2$$ until we get a negative number. Even the negative numbers can often  be prime. And we can multiply either square by the multiplier m and we can use any multiplier. It does not have to be $2$.

So the question is, how good is this simple way to generate primes? We obviously have to run a primality test to verify if the numbers generated are indeed primes.

Comment: Not better, just another way to do things. One could test both and see which one is faster in finding a prime.

Comment: @MorganRodgers, I never claimed that this simple method is more efficient. As to the purpose it may serve, I did not have in mind any purpose when I started playing with numbers. So should we discard any other way to do things just because we already have one way of doing things? So if we already know that 2+5=7, are you implying that we don't need to figure out that 10-3=7?

Comment: @MorganRodgers  And by the way analysis  of probabilities is way above "my pay grade". Let's hope someone curious enough will give it a shot.

Comment: I have one simple reason to suspect the method is good, not when compared to other methods because I have not done any comparison, but because I spent hours testing it with numbers my calculator could handle and I have always been able to get primes after few trials if not at the first trial. And here, I will point out that very often, in math and other fields, we use different methods because some of them are better adapted than other to the situation at hands. Think about root finding algorithms and why we cannot afford to discard any algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for example a number $151$ you have used can be written also as:

$13^2-2 \cdot 3^2=151$

$13^2-18 \cdot 1^2=151$

Looking for prime number $41$ you could go checking $a^2$:

...

$10^2-5 \cdot 4^2=10$

$11^2-5 \cdot 4^2=41$

In my opinion if you continue subtracting $m \cdot b^2$ or even checking for conditions whether a number is prime or not, it might be a problem locating numbers between $(N, 2N)$, where $N$ is $1000$-digit long or more.

Comment: 10^2 - 5.4^2 = 10, does not qualify because the two squares have a common factor. We should avoid that situation as specified above. I haven't really thought about to adapt this method to finding a prime between (N, 2N). But the obvious starting point is to take a square between N and 2N and start subtracting m*b^2. One of the number has to be a prime but if it is the only prime in that interval, then it may take some time to find it.

Comment: if I were looking for prime 41, I wouldn't have chosen 11^2 as the main square. I would have chosen a smaller square, something like 7^2-2*2^2=41.

Comment: The second example was to show, that you don't know what square to start with ( also $10$ is not a prime number ). Going through iterations is time consuming.

Comment: Sure, iterating is time consuming but picking a number at random is no less time consuming because there is no guarantee that the first pick will be a prime. Looking for a "prime in general" and a very specific prime ( 41 in your example) are two different issues. Looking for a specific prime is a lot more complicated and is not the purpose of this method. And I don't know of any method that can find a specific prime. After all that would mean we know how to get the  next prime which is still an open problem.

Comment: The problem I have been having with this formula is that you are starting with three unknown terms. Can your method generate primes such as: digit sum is equal 2^28?

Comment: I simply can't answer your question. The way I think about this method is this. We start with one square, it doesn't really matter which one or if it's odd or even or if it is a square of a prime or a square of a composite and we ask "how many smaller squares can I subtract from the first square to get a prime?". Now, if I were able to code, I would try to answer your question by writing a program and see if it can produce your prime but I can't. But the fact that I cannot answer the question myself does not mean the answer is no.

Comment: I think your method should have more specific purpose. Where can I apply this method? or When can I use it? I am currently working on some problem using Fermat's factorisation. If I see that applying extra term, which is $m$ in your case can help me in some way, I will let you know.